# Eclipse type 'uint16' and 'uint8' could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, avr

I'm using eclipse and I'm working on a C project on AVR, the problem here that I get the error that type 'uint16' and 'uint8' could not be resolved

here is the code

```
#ifndef ADC_H_
#define ADC_H_

#include "micro_config.h"
#include "common_macros.h"
#include "types.h"


void ADC_init(void);

uint16 ADC_readChannel(uint8 channel_num);

#endif
```

and I included the header file in which this types are defined in types.h

```
#ifndef TYPES_H_
#define TYPES_H_

typedef unsigned char bool;

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE       (0u)
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE        (1u)
#endif

#define HIGH        (1u)
#define LOW         (0u)

#define NULL_PTR    ((void*)0)

typedef unsigned char         uint8;          
typedef signed char           sint8;          
typedef unsigned short        uint16;         
typedef signed short          sint16;         
typedef unsigned long         uint32;        
typedef signed long           sint32;        
typedef unsigned long long    uint64;        
typedef signed long long      sint64;
typedef float                 float32;
typedef double                float64;

#endif
```

I still get an error that 'uint8' and 'uint16' could not be resolved

Comment: Which other `types.h` is included then? Either another `types.h` was found in the search paths, or none was found, in which case you should have seen an error being thrown by the compiler.

Comment: Also: do `micro_config.h` and/or `common_macros.h` need the types? If so, they should already include `types.h`. What happens if you move `#include <types.h>` before the other includes?

Comment: I'm confused because the compiler doens't give me any errors or warnings @Cheatah

Comment: And the other 2 includes doesn't use  `types.h` @Cheatah

Comment: _Side note:_ If you're on a 64 bit posix/linux machine, `uint32` will be 64 bits and _not_ 32. Try: `typedef unsigned int uint32;`

Comment: Slightly unrelated to the actual question: What is the argument against `#include <stdint.h>` and using the standard C types `uint8_t` etc. available since C99 (23 years ago)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this proplem by creating new workspace and Copied the project in it I don't know what was that proplem that I was facing.

Comment: You need to differentiate between the IDE and the compiler. The compiler knows where the header files live, if correctly installed. But the IDE might need some help, for example if you create a new project an automated scanner may start.

Comment: There might have been some settings in previous workspace not including the proper libraries. A comparison of entire workspaces may help understand better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).